# NPM node_modules structure changes every other time I run "npm install"

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I have two private repositories in Github with package.json that one of these repositories is dependency of another one. like this

```
Repo_A
   |
   |__ Reop_B
```

in package.json of Repo_A I have:

```
dependencies: {
   "Repo_B": "GithubUser/Repo_B"
}
```

I want to use Repo_A in my project so I run:

```
npm install GithubUser/Repo_A --save
```

This command will install both Repo_A and Repo_B
but the problem is Repo_A and Repo_B are nested (and NOT flat) in my main project's `node_molules` folder.

```
node_modules
           |
           |_Repo_A
                  |
                  |_ node_modules
                                |
                                |_Repo_B
```

and after running `npm install` agian Repo_A and Repo_B will became flat in `node_mudules` this time!

```
node_molules
           |
           |_Repo_A
           |
           |_Reop_B
```

and running `npm install` again makes Repo_A and Repo_B nested again!
and this event repeats every other time I run `npm install`
Do you have any suggestions?

**UPDATE**:

My Problem is not nested or flat dependency! my problem is that every time I run `npm install` I switch between flat and nested!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does npm3 decides to install flat vs. nested?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397193/how-does-npm3-decides-to-install-flat-vs-nested)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I've also faced this issue before.
For now I'm using `npm dedupe` after the install to make sure the dependency tree is as flat as possible.

Please take into account that [dedupe doesn't always dedupe](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19007).

Answer (score 0):

It could be disturbing, that's why npmjs has published a complete guide where they explain how they store dependencies.

https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3

> However, since B v1.0 is already a top-level dep, we cannot install B v2.0 as a top level dependency. npm v3 handles this by defaulting to npm v2 behavior and nesting the new, different, module B version dependency under the module that requires it -- in this case, module C.

Have fun

Comment: there's just one version of each repo. I don't have different versions!

Comment: Maybe you, but what about of your dependencies ? And the dependencies of the dependencies of your dependencies... npm try to flatten the most possible.

Comment: that's why when i install a new package, i completely remove node_modules and reinstall all the things